# Why won't the wandering Trader spawn?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a survival world and I really want cocoa beans, jungle saplings and bamboo, I have searched in every direction of my base for thousands of blocks for a jungle with no luck. I know you can get all of these from a wandering trader, however, it is nowhere to be found.

I know it takes time for it to appear, but I haven't heard a peep of its existence for literal days IRL. My base is set in a forest biome of which I've completely deforested (global warming don't exist in-game, sue me =D), so it has plenty of space to spawn in. occasionally, I do trade with the villages near me (there's a few) so they should have a good view of me.

I also don't get pillagers spawning near me either so I'm beginning to think it may all be a glitch within my world.

P.S. I am prepared to face the fact that I may never see it again, so if the problem doesn't resolve itself I may just have to search for a couple thousand more blocks =(

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be you already have a villager spawned somewhere but you don't know it.

> At any time, there can be only ***one*** wandering trader naturally spawned in loaded chunks. After 24000 ticks (20 real-life minutes, or 1 Minecraft day) have passed since the world is created, the game attempts to spawn a wandering trader.[note 1] If there are no wandering traders currently in any loaded chunks, the game tries to spawn a new wandering trader after every following 24000 ticks, within a 48-block radius of a player.

Source: [Official Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wandering_Trader#:%7E:text=If%20there%20are%20no%20wandering,block%20radius%20of%20a%20player.)

There is some RNG involved hre. Whenever the game tries to spawn a trader (every 24000 ticks) there is a 2.5% chance of success. If it fails, it is 5% for the next day, 7.5% for the next, etc. On an average, you should get a trader in ~10 days but if you're really unlucky eventually the chance will drive up to 100%. So if you're in the same area for a while you should get one.

If it's just the blocks and items you're after you could try this [biome finder](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/biome-finder) to get the biomes you need.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that according to the Minecraft Wiki the chance now caps at 7.5% after the third day.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue,  i had him appearing at the beggining of my world, but once i created an underground base, the trader stopped spawning with the patrols, but when i got back on surface, but after around 20 minutes he got back with the patrols.